# Formularios con Eureka

Tags: swift4

Estoy con un problema en Swift con Eureka, estoy tratando de obtener los datos del registro de un formulario en un segundo Tableview (en un Label) y cuando paso los datos (que solo estoy pasando uno para probar) me regresa el Label vacío y no estoy encontrando ni el error y menos la solución, no se donde estoy equivocándome, espero que ustedes puedan ayudarme por favor. Este es el código:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka


class ViewController: FormViewController {

 var user: String = ""
var pass: String = ""
var fecha: Date? = nil
var tel: String = ""
var genero: String = ""
var opcion: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    form +++ Section("Registro")

        <<< TextRow(){ row in
            row.title = "Usuario"
            row.placeholder = "Escribe tu nombre"
    }.onChange({(row)in
        self.user = row.value!
    })
        <<< PasswordRow(){ row in
            row.title = "Contrasena"
            row.placeholder = "Escribe tu contrasena"
    }.onChange({(row) in
        self.pass = row.value!
    })

        <<< DateRow(){
            $0.title = "Fecha de nacimiento"
            $0.value = Date()
            }.onChange({(row) in
                self.fecha = row.value!
            })



    +++ Section("Datos personales")

    <<< PhoneRow(){
        $0.title = "Celular"
        $0.placeholder = "Escribe tu numero"
        }.onChange({(row) in
            self.tel = row.value!
        })
        <<< PushRow<String>(){
            $0.title = "Genero"
            $0.options = ["Femenino","Masculino","Otro"]
            $0.value = ""
            $0.selectorTitle = "Seleciona una opcion"
            }.onChange({(row) in
                self.genero = row.value!
            })

        <<< CheckRow(){row in
            row.title = "Opcion"
            row.value = true
            }.onChange({(row) in
                self.opcion = row.value!
            })
    +++ Section("")

        <<< ButtonRow{ row in
          row.title = "Guardar"
            }.onCellSelection({(cell, row)in
               print(self.user)
               print(self.pass)
                print(self.fecha ??  "Sin fecha")
                print(self.tel)
                print(self.genero)
                print(self.opcion)



                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "enviar", sender: self)

    })

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "enviar" {
            let destino = segue.destination as! SegundoViewController

            destino.usuario = user
```

Y este es el segundo **ViewController**

```
import UIKit



class SegundoViewController: UIViewController {

var usuario: String!

@IBOutlet weak var nombredelpaciente: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Registro"

nombredelpaciente.text = usuario


}  

}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchísimas gracias!!